# Searching And highlighting searched text on Pdf for iphone app

Tags: iphone

Hi am developing book application in which am drawing 
PDF using Quartz 2d am also able to search the text for this i used the concept mention on Random ideas http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42 but am stuck on highlighting those search text i dont want to use Fastkit pdf in my Application.......
Have gone through many of us has asked the same but no one till now as replied for this...

Please guide me wid some sample code so i can processed further in my application .....

Thanxs in advance .... :)
Sanvi